# Automatically scrolling of NestedScrollView inside CoordinatorLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have main layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/RegisterVendorTabLayout"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

ViewPager has a few fragments. Each fragment has a layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:imeOptions="actionNext"/>
                    .....
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem: if user click on the button `Next` and some fields are at the bottom of the screen, keyboard will hide these fields and automatically scrolling doesn't work.

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` is `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for activity which contains this code.

Version of Support Design Library is 23.1.1.

Comment: Hi  use this line your NestedscrollView xml 
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: Hi @Vladimir, how did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: if some EditText gets focus, need to call the method `AppBarLayout#setExpanded`. So there will be enough place for scrolling NestedScrollView. Also it helped me https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/issues/95#issuecomment-80519589